# JDBI object parameter

Tags: java, mysql, jdbi

I have a question. I want to create 'insert into' query using JDBI in JAVA but I do not want to give to function all parameters, what I want is to give to funtion object. For example I don`t want something like this:

```
@SqlUpdate("INSERT INTO <database>.DZIENNIK_ROBOT (ETAP, DATA_ROBOTY, OPIS_ROBOTY, LINKI, WYKONAWCA, ID_UZYTKOWNIK, DATA_UTWORZENIA, DATA_MODYFIKACJI, CZY_USUNIETY) " +
        "VALUES (:etap,:dataRoboty,:opis,:link,:wykonawca,:idUzytkownik,now(),now(),0)")
void DodajDziennikRobot(@Define("database") String schema, @Bind("etap") String etap, @Bind("dataRoboty") Date dataRoboty, @Bind("opis") String opis,
                             @Bind("link") String link, @Bind("wykonawca") String wykonawca, @Bind("idUzytkownik") Long idUzytkownik);
```

What I want is something like this:

```
@SqlUpdate("INSERT INTO <database>.DZIENNIK_ROBOT (ETAP, DATA_ROBOTY, OPIS_ROBOTY, LINKI, WYKONAWCA, ID_UZYTKOWNIK, DATA_UTWORZENIA, DATA_MODYFIKACJI, CZY_USUNIETY) " +
        "VALUES (:etap,:dataRoboty,:opis,:link,:wykonawca,:idUzytkownik,now(),now(),0)")
void DodajDziennikRobot(@Define("database") String schema, @BindBean DziennikRobot dziennikRobot);
```

But the problem is that my model 'DziennikRobot' have more properties than those which I give to this function (normally I don`t need rest of properties in database). Can I only set chosen parameters or I must give all of them to this function?
Thanks for helps!

Answer (score 0):

It possible to give only chosen parameters. Problem were somewhere else, in data types, sorry for question.